# How to query data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","
                    +" from "+SENS_TABLE+ ","
                    +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" +id_thsen+","
                    +null+"," +null+"," +null+"," +null;
                    return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);}
```

This is the way I get Sentence list 
but if I want to change the way to write like this instead

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
                    +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","                     
                    +" from "+SENS_TABLE+","
                    +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + id_thsen+","
                    +null+"," +null+"," +null+"," +null+",";
                    return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);}
```

Is anything wrong? because it doesn't work

please help........

and This is my logcat........

> 02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.proj/com.android.proj.Sens_Show}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error: , while compiling: select Sentences._id,Sentences.id_thsen,Sentences.id_lang,Sentences.sen,Sentences.reading, from Sentences, where Sentences.id_thsen1,null,null,null,null,
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error: , while compiling: select Sentences._id,Sentences.id_thsen,Sentences.id_lang,Sentences.sen,Sentences.reading, from Sentences, where Sentences.id_thsen1,null,null,null,null,
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.proj.DBAdapter.getSen_List(DBAdapter.java:875)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Show.listData(Sens_Show.java:91)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Show.onCreate(Sens_Show.java:63)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   02-10 20:48:18.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(818):     ... 11 more

Comment: So what , all I need is someone who help me = = thanks

Comment: with that attitude you won't get much...

Comment: Well, inspect what that mess generates -- then try to run it via the sqlite CLI (command-line interface, SQLite on the PC is fine). Problem found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query strTmp results in this string (with test values):

"select tblname.key_1,tblname.key_2,tblname.key_3,tblname.key_4,tblname.key_5, from tblname, where tblname.key_24,null,null,null,null,"

So to make it a valid SQLite query, you should use this code

```
String strTmp = "select "
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING                     
        +" from "+SENS_TABLE
        +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" + id_thsen;
```

which results in:
"select tblname.key_1,tblname.key_2,tblname.key_3,tblname.key_4,tblname.key_5 from tblname where tblname.key_2=4"

Comment: It is a pleasure. The goal of this site is to build a good database of answer and replies that are validated by the people that are trying these answers. So by voting up and accepting the answers to your questions, you contribute to building a better database. If you don't people will just stop replying to your questions.

Comment: I absolutely want to vote you but I have no enough reputation, so sorry T T

Comment: Can't you click on the check mark to accept a reply as the right one? I thought no reputation points were needed for that.

Comment: Oh okay I'm new sorry for that and thank you again I accepted and checked mark for your answer ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
+" from "+SENS_TABLE"
+" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" +id_thsen+","
```

try that.

EDIT:

`+" from "+SENS_TABLE+","` should not have the last `+","`
and 
you are missing the  `+ "="` between `KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN` and `+id_thsen+","`